# Convert String to String() VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hello everyone I don't know how I can put the values I get from the list into String() format.

This is my current code:

```
 Private files As String()
files = New String() {
            "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07",
            "08", "09", "0A", "0B", "0C", "0D", "0E", "0F",
            "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17",
            "18", "19", "1A", "1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F",
            "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27",
            "28", "29", "2A", "2B", "2C", "2D", "2E", "2F",
            "30", "31"}

Dim vals As New List(Of String)()
        Dim Counter As Integer
        For Counter = 1 To 5
            vals.Add(Counter.ToString)
        Next

        files = String.Join(",", vals) 'I'm getting an error here that I can't convert String to String ()

I want to finally bob this result: files = new String() {"1","2","3","4","5"}
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: `String.Join` returns a `String`. `vals` is already a `List(Of String)`. Maybe you want `.ToArray()`. Or what do you want?

Comment: @mm8 yes it is clear to me that String.Join returns a string, how can I return ToArray()?

Comment: @mm8 I have a values values Counter.Tostring(), is it possible for this part to take values in a string? LIKE: files = Enumerable.Range(1.tostring(), 5.tostring()).toArray()

Comment: I am not sure I follow. `Enumerable.Range` accepts two `Integers`. It doesn't accept strings.

Comment: @mm8 so yes i'm clear but with me the files string () as I stated in the question and in your answer is files = integer

Comment: You can use the `Select`method to convert the integer to a string. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Join` returns a `String`. `vals` is already a `List(Of String)`...

If you want a `String()`, you can just convert the list to an array:

```
files = vals.ToArray()
```

...or avoid creating the list in the first place:

```
files = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(Function(x) x.ToString).ToArray()
```

Comment: @Mara You can also do a similar thing with that hex array `Dim files = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(Function(x) x.ToString("X2")).ToArray()`